# Nice way to show html <DIV> elements like gallery, mooflow, lightbox etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

We have number of plugins to display images in a nice manner. For eg: mooflow(http://www.outcut.de/MooFlow/example-milkbox-bridge.html) with which we can display images in mac itunes manner. But i am wondering whether we have any plugins with which we can display html DIV elements like that. I don't have any image to display, but i just want to display  series of divs where each div has some brief text content.

I will be really happy to know that there is a way to configure jquery's gallery, lightbox & mootools' mooflow to make them display divs as well apart from regular images.

Thanks,
~Shafi

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) let's you do HTML contents (see 'Inline Content' example).

Answer (score 0):

There are several modified versions of Lightbox that do this. An example is [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).  See the the inline content example.