# jquery - make a simple gallery out of a bunch of DIVs

Tags: jquery, gallery

I was wondering if anyone has something simple to create a gallery from a bunch of divs. Such as

```
<div id=gallery>
    <div class='slide' id=1><img src='image1.png'> this is image 1</div>
    <div class='slide' id=2><img src='image1.png'> this is image 1</div>
    <div class='slide' id=3><img src='image1.png'> this is image 1</div>
    <div class='slide' id=4><img src='image1.png'> this is image 1</div>
</div>
```

I like to show one DIV at a time. Clicking div advances to next slide. And at the end, it loops back to the first one.

No effects, just a simple showing of one div followed by next.

Thanks
Scott

UPDATE:

Okay, I decided to just write my own based on http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/. Anyone can make this code more tight and efficient, please add comment.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPosition = 1;
  var slides = $('.slide');
  var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

  if(currentPosition==1){ $('.slide').hide(); $('#1').show()};

  // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
  $('.slide')
    .bind('click', function(){
    currentPosition = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
    if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides) {
        $('.slide').hide(); 
        $('#1').show();
    } else {
        $('.slide').hide();
        nextPosition = parseInt(currentPosition+1);

        $('#'+nextPosition).show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: see if this is what you want http://www.allposters.com/, there is slider implemented we did recently

Comment: there are examples available here http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/

Comment: did you see example at allposters.com , i can explain you howit is done.

Comment: hi gov, that seems to be close to what i want. i just want to show a single div at a time instead of a set of divs. could you explain how it's done?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the ones suggested here to save yourself time: http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/

- Christian

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar question that got lots of answers: [Nice way to show html <DIV> elements like gallery, mooflow, lightbox etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363566/nice-way-to-show-html-div-elements-like-gallery-mooflow-lightbox-etc)

Answer (score 1):

I changed my comment as answer

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/

check our implementation recently on

www.allposters.com /// there is a slider here

Comment: is this the one you are talking about?  http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the jQuery plugin Colorbox is the best!
Very versatile and stable gallery.

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Examples
http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html

Real world implementation:
http://www.bakkerbart.nl (if you press the "bestellen" button)

Comment: @michale, he wants image slider

Comment: hmm i thought a image gallery. my bad! although colorbox is quite powerfull :D